# Count occurrences of tab in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabs

I'm trying to count the number of tabs in a string, but it always gives me 0.

```
numbers = '1\\t2\\t3\\t4\\t5'
```

And I want to return 4. But:

```
numbers.count('\\t')
```

gives 0

Comment: *"it always counts the number of spaces instead"* what does? I assume you're referring to a solution you attempted, so please edit the question to include your code.

Comment: Is it possible that ur editor transformed the tabs into spaces ?

Comment: I see the tabs as spaces in your post. I think like what @Linh mentioned, it could be something that is translating your tabs to spaces.

Comment: You probably want `numbers = '1\t2\t3\t4\t5'` for your edit. Escaping the the slash makes it literally `slash - t` not a tab. After that `numbers.count('\t')` returns `4` for me.

Comment: @Potion Seller You just completely changed the question, do you know what you want now?

Comment: @lbragile that's one of the many reasons you shouldn't answer questions that aren't clear.

Comment: @Mark Meyer seemed clear at the time, but lesson learned. Technically speaking though, anyone can change their question completely if they feel their original question wasn't really what they wanted to ask (even if it was clearly explained). I guess that's the luck of the draw :)

Comment: Yeah I realized that I wasnt asking the right question

Answer (score 6):

1. Your string does not have any tabs. A tab is represented as `'\t'`, not as `'\\t'`. The latter is a backslash followed by a `'t'`.
2. `numbers.count('\\t')` correctly reports 4.
3. This is what you probably want:

   ```
   numbers = '1\t2\t3\t4\t5'
   numbers.count('\t')
   # 4
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Count number of spaces in the input string you provided and determine how many tabs that is according to your definition of a tab.

```
def calcTabs(numbers, tab):
    split_nums = numbers.split(",")
    num_tabs = []
    for elem in split_nums:
        space_ind = elem.count(' ')
        num_tabs.append(len(space_ind)/tab)

    return num_tabs

tab = 4 # number of spaces a tab equals
numbers = '1,3    4,5 6    7    8'

list_tabs = calcTabs(numbers, tab)
print(list_tabs)
```

**Output:**

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.25]
```

As can be seen this tells you the number of tabs (even with fractions if you have 2 tabs and a space for example in this case).

---

If you want just the number of tabs (as a whole number), you can use math.floor() to do so:

```
import math 

def calcTabs(numbers, tab):
    split_nums = numbers.split(",")
    num_tabs = []
    for elem in split_nums:
        space_ind = elem.count(' ')
        num_tabs.append(math.floor(space_ind/tab))

    return num_tabs

tab = 4 # number of spaces a tab equals
numbers = '1,3    4,5 6    7    8'

list_tabs = calcTabs(numbers, tab)
print(list_tabs)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of splitting on commas here, or finding the indices of the spaces?

Comment: @kaya3 you split to tell the number of tabs at each index. Finding the indices of the spaces tell you how many there are so that you can calculate how many tabs there are - a tab is N spaces as defined by the user.

Comment: You don't need to find the indices to count them; `num_spaces = elem.count(' ')` works fine. I don't really see how your output relates to the question.

Comment: @kaya3 great point! I knew there was a simpler way but couldn't remember how. Thanks for the suggestion, I made the edit above.

Comment: I think you are counting as if a space is a fraction of a tab, which isn't really correct; a tab is a single character, not a sequence of spaces.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah that was due to OP's original `numbers` variable containing spaces. Now that they changed the question, this no longer makes sense unfortunately.

Comment: I think the original question wasn't clear what it was asking, and it was likely the code wasn't copied onto Stack Overflow correctly. For the record, if you want to count sequences of four spaces, you can do it in one line with `return numbers.count(' '*4)`.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah I agree. Wow mind-blown right there, I appreciate learning "shortcuts" like these! Thanks for the great tips :)